# Проверка длины строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Делал валидацию формы на JavaScript и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
есть поле, которое может быть пустое, либо содержать только цифры. При этом может быть 8 или 10 цифр.
Как это реализовать с помощью регулярных выражений?
Пытался сделать, но не получилось. В гугле нормально ничего не смог найти, т.к было трудно даже запрос сформулировать :)
Заранее спасибо.

П.С. Я это реализовал, но криво. Чувствую, что это можно сделать с помощью одного выражения.
Сделал так (функция для jQuery validate):

```
function(value, element) {
    if (!/[^0-9]/.test(value)) {
        if (value.length == 10 || value.length == 8 || !value.length) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: не знаю как там дела с регулярными в ЯС, но медоты, я думаю, можешь написать и сам, методы проверки на букву или цифру - должны быть, а дальше считай буквы в поле и проверяй на длину

Comment: а зачем использовать исключающий символьный класс и отрицание если можно просто числовой символьный класс?

Comment: Первое что пришло в голову просто) Спасибо что все прояснили.
Книжку по регуляркам хорошую можете посоветовать?

Comment: Дж. Фридл "Регулярные выражения"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само выражение может быть например таким:

```
^\d{8}(\d{2})?$
```

Или таким:

```
^(\d{8}|\d{10})$
```

А на пустоту без регулярки проверить проще и код понятнее будет.